# android: Navigation Drawer error in Gradle Build

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I'm trying to use a Navigation Drawer, but I can't because I get the error:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not find any version that matches com.android.support:design:21.+.
     Versions that do not match:
         26.0.0-alpha1
         25.3.1
         25.3.0
         25.2.0
         25.1.1
         + 21 more
     Required by:
         project :app
```

On gradle I have:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:21.+'
}
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try **using** this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:21.0.3'
```

**Or**:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.+'
compile 'com.android.support:design:21.+'
```